# Run function on input change and checkbox change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Bootstrap modal with multiple forms in it. All the forms have an input field and checkbox. I try to run a function `update_amounts_modal` every time a change event takes place. This working when I change the input value but doesn't work when I check/uncheck the checkbox.

**UPDATE** I'VE CREATED A FIDDLE [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sp91u542/)

The function:

```
function update_amounts_modal(){
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('form').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('.qty input').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price input').val();
    qty= parseInt(qty) || 0;
    price= parseFloat(price) || 0;
    var amount = (qty*price)
                 sum+=amount;
  });
    $('.total-modal').text('€'+sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

The change function:

```
  update_amounts_modal();
  $('form .qty').change(function(){
    update_amounts_modal();
    $('.total-modal').change();
  });
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" data-target="#modal" data-async="" action="action_url">
  <div class="qty cell">
    <input type="text" class="qty" value="1" name="quantity">
  </div>
  <div class="price cell">
    <span class="euro">€</span><input type="text" disabled="" class="price" value="0.60">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox cell">
     <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="12933006" name="product[]" class="idRow">
  </div>
</form>

//And more forms exactly like this but with different input values!

<div class="total-modal">€0.00</div>
```

What actually needs to happen is that by checking/unchecking the value needs to be recalculated with the function. So if you have set `qty` to 10 and you uncheck the checkbox then this amount (10x eg. €0.25) must be deducted from the total.

I thought something like this should work but that isn't:

```
$(".idRow").change(function(){
  if($(this).attr("checked")){
    update_amounts_modal();
  }
  else{
    update_amounts_modal();
  }
```

I don't get an error there's just nothing happening. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you call the same function in both cases?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure figure out your question correctly or not but i think you are looking for something like this:

```
function update_amounts_modal() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('form').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var isChecked = $(this).find('.idRow').prop("checked");
        if (isChecked){
            qty = parseInt(qty, 10) || 0;
            price = parseFloat(price) || 0;
            var amount = (qty * price);
            sum += amount;
        }
    });
    $('.total-modal').text('€' + sum.toFixed(2));
}

$().ready(function () {
    update_amounts_modal();
    $('form .qty, form .idRow').change(function () {
        update_amounts_modal();
    });
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sp91u542/2/)**

**Update:**

If in some forms you don't have a CheckBox (in other words some prices aren't optional) so you have to check that CheckBox exist or not and if exist, so check that is checked or not.

in order to do that, modify the update function like this:

```
function update_amounts_modal() {
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('form').each(function () {
        var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
        var checkbox = $(this).find('.idRow');
        if (checkbox.prop("checked") || checkbox.length == 0){
            qty = parseInt(qty, 10) || 0;
            price = parseFloat(price) || 0;
            var amount = (qty * price);
            sum += amount;
        }
    });
    $('.total-modal').text('€' + sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

in this line: `if (checkbox.prop("checked") || checkbox.length == 0){` we say that sum the value if checkbox is checked (`checkbox.prop("checked")`) or there is no CheckBox (`checkbox.length == 0`).

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sp91u542/3/)**

Comment: Moshtaf : You have created a really nice fiddle for explanation. Great help there..

Comment: @Moshtaf: Trust me I tried this and it didn't work. Now I see in the fiddle that it actually works but not in my modal. Does that matter? No I think. I'll accept the answer since you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I think your problem isn't that mentioned in question, you don't read state of checkboxes in calculation function, no matter checkboxes change or not, did you see this line in my answer? `if (isChecked){` i add this and also add `form .idRow` in `.change` function. i think you forgot to remove value from `sum` if checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @Moshtaf: One last question.. What if `isChecked` returns undefined? How can bypass that so that the `update_amounts_modal` still calculates the total?

Answer (score 2):

Try this : Instead of attr use prop

```
$(".idRow").change(function(){
   if($(this).prop("checked")){
    update_amounts_modal();
   }
   else{
       update_amounts_modal();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ttried this before but that still doesn't update the total amount. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You said that "doesn't work when I check/uncheck the checkbox" .. The above answer solves the issue related to functions being called when you check/uncheck the checkbox. It does not solve the issue inside the function which you will have to do..

Answer (score 0):

u can do

```
<div class="checkbox cell">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>

jQuery("div.checkbox > input:checkbox").on('click',function(){
    alert('asdasd');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1r7rk21w/

Comment: Tried this before but that still doesn't update the total amount. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've created a fiddle. You can see exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the values to update based on the checked property, then your sum function needs to actually use that check box right?

JS:

```
$('form').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(".idRow").prop("checked") === true){
        //
        // The normal computations you had before...
        //
    } 
});
```